# Reverting a commit in SVN?

Tags: svn, version-control

How can i revert a commit having the following situation?

```
Revision 3, Commit Message
Revision 2, Commit Message
Revision 1, Commit Message
```

Revision 2 is a bad commit and i want to remove it. How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can undo commits via the reverse merge in SVN:

Assuming you have a working copy which is checked out from trunk:

```
svn merge -c -2 URL/trunk
```

This will undo the changes you've made in the revision 2 and leave you a working copy with changes which you need to commit.

This will not change the history, cause it's not possible in SVN to change the history of already checked in revisions. Only via a dump/load cycle on the repository server it's possible to completely remove a revision which i can't recommend.

Comment: They will be left untouched. You only get the deltas from rev 1 to 2 and apply them in reverse order on your working copy. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

On a checkout:

```
  svn merge -r2:1 path/to/checkout
  svn ci -m'Undo changes in rev 2 ' path/to/checkout
```

If you want it completely out of the repo, you need to dump, filter & load it into a new one on the repo-server.